# Equation from $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb C$ in terms of $z$ and $\bar z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Derive an equation involving only $z$ and $\bar z$ satisfied by the points in $\mathbb C$ which lie on the straight line whose equation in $\mathbb R^2$ is
$\frac{x}{a}$ + $\frac{y}{b}$ = 1 , where a and b are non-zero real constants.

So far, I've transformed the equation into $y=-\frac{b}{a}x+b$, so it's a linear equation in $\mathbb R^2$, but I'm not sure how to move this into $\mathbb C$ in terms of z and $\bar z$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $x=\frac{z+\bar z}2$. There is a similar one for $y$.

Comment: So, $\frac{z-\bar z}{2i}$= -$\frac{b}{a} (\frac{z+\bar z}{2})+b$.   But is there a way to get rid of the $i$?

Comment: @MarissaB No, I don't think there is. Why would that be necessary? You have an equation where the variable is expected to be complex, there shouldn't be a problem using complex coefficients.

Comment: Ah okay thank you, I was just wondering about the question asking for only $z$ and $\bar z$, and thought $i$ might not be allowed to be included, or if it's even possible to not include it.

Comment: You're allowed to use $2$, and there is no conceptual difference between $2$ and $i$ in this context. At least, if your teacher thinks it is, then that's a bad teacher.